# opencart category module with thumb name and description

Tags: php, module, opencart, categories

I want to make a module with the current category name, description and image(thumb)

The code gives me only the main category which should be the current category. How to manage that? Also i have the category banner in my module. Is there a way to get that out of the $category['description']

Hope someone can help. I tried to find clues from oter scripts but that didn't work. Copying from the category.tpl didn't do the trick either.

I have this in controler / category

```
<?php  
class ControllerModuleLbMultiLevelCategory extends Controller {
    public function index($setting) {
        $this->load->language('module/lbmultilevelcategory');

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);
        } else {
            $parts = array();
        }

        if (isset($parts[0])) {
            $data['category_id'] = $parts[0];
        } else {
            $data['category_id'] = 0;
        }

        if (isset($parts[1])) {
            $data['child_id'] = $parts[1];
        } else {
            $data['child_id'] = 0;
        }

        if (isset($parts[2])) {
            $data['sisters_id'] = $parts[2];
        } else {
            $data['sisters_id'] = 0;
        } 

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $data['categories'] = array();

        $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts(array('filter_category_id' => $category['category_id']));

            $children_data = array();

            $sister_data = array();

            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

            foreach ($children as $child) {           
                $sister_data = array();
                $sisters = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);
                if($sisters) {
                    foreach ($sisters as $sisterMember) {
                        $sister_data[] = array(
                            'category_id' =>$sisterMember['category_id'],
                            'name'        => $sisterMember['name'],

                            'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']. '_' . $sisterMember['category_id'])   
                            );                     

                    }
                    $children_data[] = array(
                        'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                        'sister_id'   => $sister_data,
                        'name'        => $child['name'],

                        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])   
                        );   
                } else {                     
                    $children_data[] = array(
                        'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                        'sister_id'    =>'',
                        'name'        => $child['name'],

                        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])   
                        );   
                }
            }

           // image cat code
            $this->load->model('tool/image');
            $image = empty($category['image']) ? 'no_image.jpg' : $category['image'];
            $thumb = $this->model_tool_image->resize($image, 50, 50);

            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
                'name'        => $category['name'], 
                'children'    => $children_data,
                'sister'    => $sister_data,
                'thumb'    => $thumb,
                'description' => $category['description'],
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
                );  
        }

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/lbmultilevelcategory.tpl')) {
            return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/lbmultilevelcategory.tpl', $data);
        }else {
            return $this->load->view('default/template/module/category.tpl', $data);
        }

    }

}
```

and have this for view tpl

```
<?php if ($categories) :

      foreach ($categories as $category) { 

      if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { 

      if(isset($category)) { 
      ?>
      <h2> <?php
  echo (html_entity_decode($category['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')); ?> </h2>

<?php  echo (html_entity_decode($category['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')); ?>

<?php
}
 }
 } ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```